# Why does Odoo 17 not render a label for my field in a <notebook>?

Tags: odoo, odoo-17

I am running the tutorial on Odoo 17 development, and I created this code for the exercise in [chapter 7](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/tutorials/getting_started/07_basicviews.html#tutorials-getting-started-07-basicviews):

```
<record id="estate_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">estate.property.form</field>
    <field name="model">estate.property</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Estate Property" create="True">
            <sheet>
                <group string="Info">
                    <field name="name" />
                    <field name="description" />
                </group>
                <group string="Location">
                    <field name="postcode" />
                </group>
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Specs">
                        <field name="facades" />
                        <field name="garage" />
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

It works, but the label for the fields in the `<notebook>` are not rendered. I tried adding a `string` attribute, but that doesn't work. The [documentation on `<notebook>`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/user_interface/view_architecture.html#notebook-page-tabbed-section) doesn't say anything about this behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC since every version i've used (6.1+) you have to have a `group` around `field`s to automatically get labels.

```xml
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Specs">
                        <group>
                            <field name="facades" />
                            <field name="garage" />
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
```